unknown type name 'SAL_acquire'
I am worknig on an application that runs on Windows 10 prompt. I am using Windows APIs, the program language is C and GCC as compiler. One year ago I was able to compile this project without errors, today I am getting this (this is only a part of what I got):
gcc -c -o obj/ASCIIsnake_func.o ASCIIsnake_func.c -I../include
In file included from c:\mingw\include\kernelspecs.h:36:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\winnt.h:101,
                 from c:\mingw\include\windef.h:269,
                 from c:\mingw\include\excpt.h:54,
                 from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:171,
                 from ASCIIsnake_func.c:6:
c:\mingw\include\DriverSpecs.h:380:18: error: unknown type name 'SAL_acquire'
     __ANNOTATION(SAL_acquire(__In_impl_ char *);)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\DriverSpecs.h: In function '__ANNOTATION':
c:\mingw\include\DriverSpecs.h:390:5: error: expected declaration specifiers before '__ANNOTATION'
     __ANNOTATION(SAL_release(__In_impl_ char *);)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\DriverSpecs.h:390:49: error: expected declaration specifiers before ')' token
     __ANNOTATION(SAL_release(__In_impl_ char *);)
                                            ^

GCC version:
C:\Users\pc>gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

It seems that some library is missing. I tryied to reinstall GCC and Windows SDK, but this did not help.
Also, these enviroment variables are set:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\MinGW\bin
C:\MinGW\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.26100.0\um
C:\ProgramData\mingw64\mingw64\bin


You might just be missing an #include <SAL.h> directive or the <SAL.h> file you're using is outdated (see SAL Annotations). Keep in mind GCC is not a supported compiler. Use MSVC or Clang instead.
